# Can someone please tell me the name or purpose of this tool? Thanks

Tags: tools

Please identity this tool. Thanks. [image]

Comment: really? ..... you are going to provide only a picture? ..... you cannot think of any other information that you could provide?

Comment: Is the entire thing metal?

Comment: Where did you find it ? I'm pretty sure it's suppose to go on something. It doesn't really look like a tool, more of a component really.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please [register](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 7):

https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/04618823

It is a draw cleco used for sheet metal work to hold sheets together while riveting adjacent holes. Black usually means 5/32 diameter.